# Deciding on the number of solutions of a system of nonlinear equations by converting the system into an optimization problem

Tags: convex-analysis, nonlinear-system

Suppose that we want to find out if the following system of equations have a unique solution:
$$
g_i(x)=0 \quad i=1,2,\ldots,m, 
$$
where $x \in {\Bbb R}^n$ and $g_i(x)$ is any arbitrary function $g_i: {\Bbb R}^n \rightarrow {\Bbb R} $.

In general, showing that a nonlinear system of equations has a unique solution can be hard.

Consider the following optimization problem:

$$
\min\ \sum_i g_i(x)^2
$$

If the objective function turns out to be convex, then can we conclude that the original system of nonlinear equations has at most one unique solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is **NO**. However if the objective is strictly convex the system has atmost one solution.

Comment: Yes I wanted to say strictly convex in the original question but I made a mistake and forgot  that.